# Getting the same number of frames/images from a video stream that I originally put in

Tags: images, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg in a winform application.

In my scenario I take 20 sparate jpeg images and add them to a ogg file.
I then extract all the images from that ogg file (as a test).
Despite making sure that the -r (for input) macthes -r (for output) I do not get the same number of images.

If I use, say -r 1 (for input an output) I get 3 frames.
If I use, -r 10 I get 5 frames.
If I use -r 20 I get 22 frames.

Obviousy, I am not understanding the paramters properly.

Can any advise me please?

Thanks.

My code:

For create the ogg:

```
" -f mjpeg -i - -r 30 -c:v libtheora -q:v 7 -r 30 -f ogg -";
```

For extracting the images:

```
"-i - -qscale 1 h:\\out\\img-%05d.jpg";
```

Comment: Does this page help: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link.  I cannot get it to work.  Using this  " -r 1 -f mjpeg -i - -c:v libtheora -q:v 7 -r 1 -f ogg -";  and I get no images at all :(

Comment: Are your sure your input is mjpeg? Unless you know for sure otherwise, its probably just plain jpeg.

Comment: hi again.  Should I use jpeg instead of mjpeg do you think?

Comment: Here's what I think you should do: Try one of the worked examples from that page. It isn't exactly what you want, but will verify that ffmpeg is working. Then, change *one* thing at a time until you get there. If during this process you find yourself asking a question in the form of "Should I try...?" the answer is yes. TRY IT AND SHARE YOUR RESULTS. What do you have to lose by trying?

Comment: Hi, I should have phrased my previous comment better.  I DID try jpeg instead of mjpeg but got an error straight away.  The reason I asked should I try was because it was not mentioned on that page you kindly sent me.  I was really asking for clarification of what you were suggesting. I did try the few examples but the number of frames outputted did not equal the number of frames inputted.  So same problem. Appreciate your time

Comment: I do know ffmpeg is working as in my original question.  the issue I got is proper use of the arguments.

Comment: @daxlerod Hi again, I  mis-typed the argument from that page. For anyone follwoing this the argments are:  -f mjpeg -r 30 -i - -c:v libtheora -q:v 7 -r 30 -f ogg -

Comment: @daxlerod If you re-post your original comment as a reply I can give you a green tick? :)